# Visual Studio get position

Tags: vb.net, position

I have a little question. Is there any way I could get a position inside of visual studio application? I mean then the application is started.
For exemple, I have a windows player on background, and I want to mark the position of buttons from the video and after it set my buttons to that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of multiple ways.

1. Create a button to display it's current location. Then make other button's location that spot.
2. Take a screenshot and find out the pixel location on your desired button.
3. Write a simple addon to find out your mouse's location using mouse hook.

Comment: The button I want to get location is into the video, which are played with windows media player (on background)
If I will find a pixel location or use any program to get the mouse location, I won't get the desktop location?
Can you please give me code for addon?

Comment: I wrote this little app for you
http://www.mediafire.com/download/yxfrbcs2ff453ph/MousePosition.exe